# Invalid top-level property "external_links"

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have the following  docker-compose file content:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  local-app:
    build: ./app/
    command: node app
    ports:
      - '7001:7001'
    links:
      - search-svc 
networks:
  docker_app-network:
    external: true
external_links:
  -search-svc
```

Basically what I 'm trying to do is to link the ' local-app ' container with another already running container the ' search-svc '. By running the docker compose I get the following error:

> The Compose file './docker-compose.yaml' is invalid because:
>   Invalid top-level property "external_links". Valid top-level sections for this Compose file are: secrets, version, volumes, services, configs, networks, and extensions starting with "x-". You might be seeing this error because you're using the wrong Compose file version. Either specify a supported version (e.g "2.2" or "3.3") and place your service definitions under the `services` key, or omit the `version` key and place your service definitions at the root of the file to use version 1.

I have read the documentation but I can't find any solution to my problem. 
Can anyone suggest anything that might help?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yaml files are space sensitive. You tried to define `external_links` at the top level of the file rather than as part of a service. This should by syntactically correct:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  local-app:
    build: ./app/
    command: node app
    ports:
      - '7001:7001'
    links:
      - search-svc 
    external_links:
      - search-svc
networks:
  docker_app-network:
    external: true
```

That said, linking is deprecated in docker, it is preferred to use a common network (excluding the default bridge network named `bridge`) and then use the integrated DNS server for service discovery. It looks like you have defined your common network but didn't use it. This would place your service on that network and rely on DNS:

```
version: '3.4'
services:
  local-app:
    build: ./app/
    command: node app
    ports:
      - '7001:7001'
    networks:
      - docker_app-network
networks:
  docker_app-network:
    external: true
```

Comment: Thanks BMitch. I removed the linking and added the network as you suggested. It's working fine now.