# Having trouble setting .env variables in docker compose file

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I'm trying to follow Docker docs and SO suggestions, but still getting "variable not set" errors on just trying to "docker-compose up db".  Can someone please check my .env and yaml file?  Both are in the same directory but it doesn't seem yml is reading .env???

.env:

```
FS_NAME=MY_BLOG_NAME
FS_REGION=us-east-2
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_USER=postgres
DB_PASS=$$323MY_PASS$&84
DB_NAME=postgres
```

docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3.7'
volumes:
    db_data:

x-shared_environment: &shared_environment
   LOG_LEVEL: ${LOG_LEVEL:-debug}
   DATABASE_HOST: ${DB_HOST}
   DATABASE_NAME: ${DB_NAME}
   DATABASE_USERNAME: ${DB_USERNAME}
   DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DB_PASSWORD}

services:
  app:
    image: MY_BLOG_NAME:latest
    build:
      context: .
    environment:
      <<: *shared_environment
      FS_NAME: ${FS_NAME}
      FS_REGION: ${FS_REGION}
    depends_on:
    - db
    ports:
      - '8080:8080'
      
db:
    image: postgres:12.2-apline
    volumes:
        -db_data/var/lib/postrgresql/data/pgdata
    environment:
        PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        POSTGRES_USER: {DB_USERNAME}
        POSTGRESS_PASSWORD: {DB_PASSWORD}
        POSTGRES_DB: {DB_NAME}
        POSTGRESS_PASSWORD: {DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
        -'5432:5432'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify the directory of your `.env` file, add `env_file` configuration for each service.

https://docs.docker.com/compose/environment-variables/

For exapmle:

```
db:
    image: postgres:12.2-apline
    volumes:
        -db_data/var/lib/postrgresql/data/pgdata
    env_file: 
        - ./.env
    environment:
        PGDATA: /var/lib/postgresql/data/pgdata
        POSTGRES_USER: {DB_USERNAME}
        POSTGRESS_PASSWORD: {DB_PASSWORD}
        POSTGRES_DB: {DB_NAME}
        POSTGRESS_PASSWORD: {DB_PASSWORD}
    ports:
        -'5432:5432'
```

Comment: I actually got the env variables right (but also added ur suggestion). Once env variables fixed... my final error on running docker-compose up db is: 

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Invalid top-level property "db". Valid top-level sections for this Compose file are: version, services etc....  NOTE: that to get the env variables working correctly I changed my original version from 3.7 to 3.8 (to support my latest docker v install). Any idea what the top property db error is?

Comment: note: I did not add a separate env_file for the services because my .env file has all variables for FS, DB and AWS.  So " - ./.env" should suffice?  any thoughts on the top level db error?

Comment: You can't define the `env_file` at the top level of the file, it should be configured for each service seperatly https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48154093/invalid-top-level-property-external-links

Comment: I figured it out... "db" needed to be indented... thx.for the help along the way.  